# rawQuery argument can pass in (IN clause)

Tags: android

How can I pass argument to `IN clause rawQuery`,

```
String[] argument{"1,2,3,4", "1001"};
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select  COALESCE(count(inId), 0) as invoiceCount 
from invoices where isActive = 1 AND inStat IN(?) AND inTypeId = ?", argument);
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: try using android room library.

Comment: tried `IN(?,?,?,?)` ? and argument: `{"1","2","3","4","1001"}`

Comment: "1","2","3","4" are not static they may be increase or decrease.
And "1,2,3,4" is first parameter.

Comment: did you try it? if so, does it work?

Comment: thank you.
my problem is sol
for your suggestion IN(?,?,?,?)